# Why not add ThreadChannelConnectionFactory auto-injection in RabbitAutoConfiguration?

Tags: spring-boot

1.I know that CachingConnectionFactory performs better in terms of performance, but it still has order issues when sending messages.

2.Since the project already provides ThreadChannelConnectionFactory, why not support controlling which ConnectionFactory to auto-inject through RabbitProperties?